# struct type embedded fields access

Tags: go

I am trying to learn `golang` and at moment I am trying to understand pointers. I defined three struct type

```
type Engine struct {      
    power int             
}                         
                          
type Tires struct {       
    number int            
}                         
                          
                          
type Cars struct {           
    *Engine               
    Tires                 
}
```

As you can see, in the Cars struct I defined an embedded type pointer *Engine. Look in the main.

```
func main() {                    
                                     
    car := new(Cars)             
    car.number = 4               
    car.power = 342     
    fmt.Println(car)            
}
```

When I try to compile, I've got the following errors

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x23bb]
```

How can I access the power field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
type Engine struct {      
    power int             
}                         

type Tires struct {       
    number int            
}                         


type Cars struct {           
    Engine               
    Tires                 
}
```

and than:

```
car := Cars{Engine{5}, Tires{10}}
fmt.Println(car.number)
fmt.Println(car.power)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/_4UFFB7OVI

---

If you want a pointer to the `Engine`, you must initialize your `Car` structure as:

```
car := Cars{&Engine{5}, Tires{10}}
fmt.Println(car.number)
fmt.Println(car.power)
```

Answer (score 10):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Engine struct {
    power int
}

type Tires struct {
    number int
}

type Cars struct {
    *Engine
    Tires
}

func main() {
    car := new(Cars)
    car.Engine = new(Engine)
    car.power = 342
    car.number = 4
    fmt.Println(car)
    fmt.Println(car.Engine, car.power)
    fmt.Println(car.Tires, car.number)
}
```

Output:

```
&{0x10328100 {4}}
&{342} 342
{4} 4
```

The unqualified type names `Engine` and `Tires` act as the field names of the respective anonymous fields.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Struct types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)
>
> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is an
>   anonymous field, also called an embedded field or an embedding of the
>   type in the struct. An embedded type must be specified as a type name
>   T or as a pointer to a non-interface type name *T, and T itself may
>   not be a pointer type. The unqualified type name acts as the field
>   name.

Comment: ++. Especially note `car.Engine` and `car.Tires`: every so often you need to get at the embedded object to call a method or use an operator on it; that's how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

One more example, in case of not unique field names

```
package embeded

import "fmt"

type Engine struct {
    id    int
    power int
}

type Tires struct {
    id     int
    number int
}

type Cars struct {
    id int
    Engine
    Tires
}

func Embed() Cars {
    car := Cars{
        id:     3,
        Engine: Engine{id: 1, power: 5},
        Tires:  Tires{id: 2, number: 10},
    }
    fmt.Println(car.number)
    fmt.Println(car.power)
    fmt.Println(car.id)
    fmt.Println(car.Engine.id)
    fmt.Println(car.Tires.id)
    return car
}
```